# AngularJS in innerHTML with SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert2

I'm trying to build an sign in/sign up form in SweetAlert.

Everything works fine but I'm trying to put an select with options that are made of ng-repeat from my array.

This is my code :

Part of my innerHTML:

```
var registerForm = document.createElement("div");
registerForm.innerHTML = "<form><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-6\"><label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"firstname\"><b>Firstname:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"firstname\" class=\"form-control\"> 
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"lastname\"><b>Lastname:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"lastname\" class=\"form-control\">
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"login\"><b>Login:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"login\" class=\"form-control\"> 
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"password\"><b>Password:</b></label><input type=\"password\" id=\"password\" class=\"form-control\"> 
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"password-again\"><b>Repeat Password:</b></label><input type=\"password\" id=\"password-again\" class=\"form-control\"></div> 
<div class=\"col-lg-6\"><label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"email\"><b>E-Mail:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"email\" class=\"form-control\">
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"city\"><b>City:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"city\" class=\"form-control\"> 
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"postal\"><b>Postal Code:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"postal\" class=\"form-control\"> 
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"adress\"><b>Adress:</b></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"adress\" class=\"form-control\">
<label style=\"float: left;\" for=\"country\"><b>Country:</b></label><select class=\"form-control\" ng-model=\"countires\" required><option ng-repeat=\"item in countries\" value=\"{{item.id}}\">{{item.name}}</option></select>
</div>
<div class=\"col-lg-12\"><p style=\"float:left;\">Fields marked with <span class=\"redstar\"><b>*</b></span> are required.</p></div></div></form>";
```

My swal and how I put my html in it:

```
$scope.registerSwal = function(){
    swal({
      title: 'Sign Up',
      text: 'Create a new account.',
      content: registerForm,
      buttons: {
        stop: {
        text: "Cancel",
        className: "red-modal-button",
        },
        ok: {
          text: "Register",
          value: "ok",
          className: "green-modal-button",
        },
      }
    });
}
```

My countries array :

```
$scope.countries = {1 : {name: 'Poland', id: 1}, 1 : {name: 'Holland', id: 2}};
```

This is the output:
[image: swal]

Problem is that my `ng-repeat` in select option in `innerHTML` doesn't work. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Why do use DOM manipulations and how / where do you use it?

Comment: I do it because SweetAlert content doesn't accept html. So i made my innerHTML and have put is as content of my swal. It works good but innerHTML doesn't read my angularjs ng-repeat. I will add screenshot in my question.

Comment: So, instead of using ng-repeat use ng-options. <select class=\"form-control\" ng-model=\"country\" ng-options=\"obj as obj.name for obj in countries\"  required><option value="">Please Select</option></select> And remember you need to first intialize countries in the controller file like $scope.countries = [id: 1, name: ''India"];

Comment: @Surjeet Bhadauriya Doesn't work also as it's an angularjs tag and innerHTML doesn't read it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't manipulate your DOM in AngularJS witihout using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children.

**Note:** `$scope.countries` isn't an array. I transformed it into an array.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-directive countries="countries"></my-directive>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [
      {name: 'Poland', id: 1},
      {name: 'Holland', id: 2}
    ];
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        countries: '='
      },
      template: `<form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"><label style="float: left;" for="firstname"><b>Firstname:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="lastname"><b>Lastname:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="login"><b>Login:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="login" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="password-again"><b>Repeat Password:</b></label>
                    <input type="password" id="password-again" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"><label style="float: left;" for="email"><b>E-Mail:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="city"><b>City:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="postal"><b>Postal Code:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="postal" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="adress"><b>Adress:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="adress" class="form-control">
                    <label style="float: left;" for="country"><b>Country:</b></label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="countires" required>
                        <option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.id}}">
                            {{item.name}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p style="float:left;">Fields marked with <span class="redstar"><b>*</b>
                    </span> are required.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>` 
    }
});
```

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7symv5n/)**

Comment: Okey. I understand it. Thank you very much for the response. But how can i use it as my SweetAlert content now ?

Comment: @W.Lukasiewicz updated + added an demo fiddle. Now your ng-repeat does work. I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Iin. As i said. Thank you :) It works in my html view. But i can't really set it now as content of my SweetAlert and that's what i am trying to do.

Comment: @W.Lukasiewicz you should use https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert since this supports AngularJS. You could also create a directive which handles the native function of SweetAlert.

Comment: @Iin It was helpful with my further project but i didn't fix the form inside the sweetalert and just went for normal modal window of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile `registerForm` into the scope to use the `ng-repeat` on the scope.

```
$compile(registerForm)($scope);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the duplicate keys in the object and it works.

```
$scope.countries = {1 : {name: 'Poland', id: 1}, 2 : {name: 'Holland', id: 2}};
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/pE6EGWS5oV4WUEzCzrCr?p=preview

Comment: This was a mistake but that's not why it doesn't work in innerHTML.